# SEO and 404 error redirection

Tags: seo

Recently I've removed some products and categories from my Magento store and that generated some many 404 errors as the pages where in the research index and now they doesn't exist anymore.

I was thinking about developing/using a module that takes the request to the store when they should give 404 and use keywords from the request URL to build a search query on the website so the customers doesn't get stop by a dead link.

But the question is:
will that kill my SEO?
How does Google, for instance, couple with the 404 error suppression?
As anyone else encountered this problem and tried something like this?

Since the operation will take quite some time, I would like some feedback before going into this road.

As now, I only know that redirecting 404 error to the homepage or another page is bad as it keeps dead links alive, but redirecting with a criteria will have the same "zombifing" effect?

Comment: If they're links to dead items, why does it matter if Google stops ranking you for them? You're not selling the item any more.

Comment: Customer click on that link, get 404, I sell similar items that replace it, I lost a potential purchase action

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, I would suggest using a 301 redirect to either a related product page or your homepage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In their SEO guide Google recommends building a nice custom 404 page for your case (do not forget to return 404 status code).

Abstractly quoting: "*A good custom 404 page will help people find the information they're looking for, as well as providing other helpful content and encouraging them to explore your site further.*"

Google's recommendations about 404 pages are available [here](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=93641).
Also do not forget to check their [starter SEO guide](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/www.google.com/en//webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf) in the "Best Practices" chapter.

I would just try to follow the recommendations as close as possible.

Good luck!

Comment: So instead of "cheating" and redirecting the 404, with a 200 code to a search page that is related to the URL that generated the error, you suggest to let the 404 stay there and, maybe, put that search thing in page itself?

Comment: Not me - google suggests that."If you have access to your server, we recommend that you create a custom 404 page." This is much more important than my own suggestions :-)

Comment: It is a "Too good to be true" case :-) Thanks for your time lucho.

Answer (score 0):

As solution is already mentioned over here i would like to add few words to this,
one doesn't need to be worried about their numbers of 404 pages shown in webmaster tools because it is natural that you create and delete you webpages. All you need to do is set a proper custom 404 pages so when user lands on pages that is no longer available they can easily navigate to the similar stuff they would be desiring from your website.

This will increase good user experience and Google loves those sites which caters their visitors in best manner.